# ListPlot Inset coordinates problem

Tags: plotting, graphics

Inset seem better suited for ad-hoc labels and legends than for precision, programmatic placement of annotation.

Given the following 'bottom-up' graphic expression:

```
Graphics[{
  Darker@Blue, 
  Point /@ Table[{k, Last@CountSelectMouseEvents["049", k]}, {k, -10, 
     10, 0.1}],
  Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 55}}], Text["55", {0, 55}, {2, 0}], 
  Darker@Green, Line[{{1.3, 0}, {1.3, 37}}], 
  Text["37", {1.3, 37}, {-2, 0}]
  }, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True]
```

Which yields:

[image]

How can the annotation graphics:

```
Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 55}}], Text["55", {0, 55}, {2, 0}], 
      Darker@Green, Line[{{1.3, 0}, {1.3, 37}}]
```

be `Inset` in `ListPlot` to create the same graphic? (use random points in lieu of CountSelectMouseEvents). I can never get the placement precise enough given the oblique syntax and placement rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{k, k^2}, {k, -10, 10, 0.1}], 
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 55}}], Text["55", {5, 55}, {2, 0}],
            Darker@Green, Line[{{1.3, 0}, {1.3, 37}}]}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image]

`torn[]` credit: @Heike

Comment: I see, so Inset is unnecessary.

Comment: @alancalvitti As you already said `Inset seem better suited for ad-hoc labels and legends`

Comment: Yes but somehow I thought it was necessary with Epilog. Oh well there's a million combinations of functions to become familiar with.